# JGraphX - Autolayout edges only

Tags: jgraphx, jgraph

Is there anyway i can a run auto-layout on graph edges only? 
I have a lot of fixed vertexes that i do not want to move/rearrange, but i do want to fix edges that overlap my cell/vertexes.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The layouts, namely `mxIGraphLayout` implementations, concern themselves with visible cells only, and they access those via the `mxGraph` object API. So the proper solution is to subclass `mxGraph` and override the `isCellVisible(Object cell)` method according to your needs. This way you'd create an alternate view of your graph.

Of course, you can also change the actual cell visibility in the model (`graph.getModel().setVisible(cell, false)`) and restore it back after the layout execution. But that seems like a hack.

Alternatively you could subclass the layout class itself and override these methods:

```
public boolean isVertexMovable(Object vertex)
{
    return graph.isCellMovable(vertex);
}

public boolean isVertexIgnored(Object vertex)
{
    return !graph.getModel().isVertex(vertex)
            || !graph.isCellVisible(vertex);
}

public boolean isEdgeIgnored(Object edge)
{
    mxIGraphModel model = graph.getModel();

    return !model.isEdge(edge) || !graph.isCellVisible(edge)
            || model.getTerminal(edge, true) == null
            || model.getTerminal(edge, false) == null;
}
```